# Image Magick - Converting text to image - is there a way to center the text to the middle of the image?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a simple text file that reads something like "It is 28 degrees today" I am trying to use imagemagick to center it to the middle of the image. The command i am using is this right now

```
    `convert -background lightblue -fill blue  -size 165x70 filename.txt image.png`
```

I tried using gravity but it always put the text outside of the image for some reason. I am not using it correctly from what I can see. I would like it to be centered. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 28):

```
convert \
    -size 165x70 \
    xc:lightblue \
    -font Bookman-DemiItalic \
    -pointsize 12 \
    -fill blue \
    -gravity center \
    -draw "text 0,0 'It is 28 degrees today'" \
    image.png
```

If you want to pull the input from an existing file, just feed that to the draw command:

```
convert \
    -size 165x70 \
    xc:lightblue \
    -font Bookman-DemiItalic \
    -pointsize 12 \
    -fill blue \
    -gravity center \
    -draw "text 0,0 '$(cat file.txt)'" \
    image.png
```

Comment: Since I have a text file with it already, i would like to convert that file instead of typing it in to the command. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Look At this

```
convert temp.jpg -gravity Center  -pointsize 30 -annotate 0 'Love you      
mom' temp1.jpg
```

'i love u mom' text word
gravity positioning center place of the text