# How to create thumbnail image from a text file?

Tags: javascript, image, thumbnails

I have text files in txt and md format. How can I create thumbnail images from these files? This conversion should work similar as in Google Docs or Google Drive. See screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772299/generate-thumbnail-for-text-file) Has a similar question with some answers.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you:
[generate thumbnail for text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772299/generate-thumbnail-for-text-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate thumbnail for text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772299/generate-thumbnail-for-text-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772299/generate-thumbnail-for-text-file

Comment: Thanks, guys, I saw that answer, but I suspect that quality of a thumbnail obtained by the recommended method (imagettftext) is not going to be good. The example provided here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php shows the text to be too big and not well positioned. I might be wrong as I did not actually tested it on practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need this for some small number of files and it can be done beforehand or dynamically?

If it is a small number and can be done before, use https://convertio.co/txt-svg/ tool and then save svg images for later use.

Comment: This needs to be done dynamically by users similarly as on Google Drive, Google Docs.