# Convert text to image breaking the text down into multiple columns when it exceedes the defined dimensions

Tags: imagemagick

I have seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826379/image-magick-converting-text-to-image-is-there-a-way-to-center-the-text-to-t), but I wish to convert, say poetry, into a wallpaper. (something more advanced I suppose)

Poetry is usually long, and in order to fit it in one wallpaper (fullHD), there should be some way to break it down into columns, creating a new column, once the height of the image was exceeded.

Is there a way to do this via ImageMagick?

Or should I edit the text manually, namely:

- figure out the proper height of the text and how much fits in,
- break down the text file into multiple text files where appropriate,
- create an image using each of those text files taking into account the proper gap between columns.

Comment: ImageMagick will not automatically make new columns. It will wrap text using caption:"some text"

Comment: Can't you just do that with a word processor/typesetting application and then convert the output to an image format (or take a screenshot of the result?)

Comment: @xenoid Indeed, haven't thought of it. I will try later and will describe here how I achieved this.